# Specify an object to model a random effect in mixed model

Tags: r, sas, mixed-models, random-effects

I would like to run a mixed model in R specifycing the object for the structure of a random effect.

My model is this:

```
model1=lme(methane~fixedfactor1,
           random=(~1|factory),
           data=df,method="REML")
```

I have then an object named "factory_relationship" that I would like to use to model the structure of the random effect "factory".

If it can help, I did it in SAS by using the following:

```
proc mixed data=methane_data NOINFO;
class fixedfactor1;
model methane= fixedfactor1;
random factory/type=lin(1) LDATA=factory_relationship;
run;
```

However, I could not find any solutions in R.
Could you please help me?
Best

I tried to read the PDF guidelines for both "nlme" and "lme4" R packages, but I could not find any hint.

Comment: I'm not sure you know what a call object is. What does 'I have then an object call "factory_relationship"' mean?

Comment: call was a typo. I modified it... factory_relationship is a matrix object in R, where I have the variance/covariances among the factories.

Comment: Pinheiro and Bates (2000) is referenced in `help("lme")`. It shows how to specify specific random effects structures. Maybe study `help("pdClasses")`.

Comment: In your `proc mixed` statement you didn't specify the `/subject=idno` for the random effects

Comment: It would be useful if you shared an extract of your data to understand which variables you have to use.